# Assigning global variables V assigning function attributes in Python

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, attributes, global-variables

I've figured out two ways of assigning global variables.

The first method assigns an attribute to a function.

The second method changes a global variable name.

I will be implementing this into a text-based adventure game.

What method is most suitable for my task and why?

Here is the code.

```
# Method 1. Assigning attributes to function.

def coin():
    print "You see a coin. Pick it up?"

    choice = raw_input("> ")

    if choice == "yes":
        coin.amount = coin.amount + 1
        print coin.amount
    elif choice == "no":
        print "No monies for you."


# Method 2. Assigning global name within function. 

def coin2():
    global purse
    print "You see a coin. Pick it up?"

    choice = raw_input("> ")

    if choice == "yes":
        purse = purse + 1
        print purse
    elif choice == "no":
        print "No monies for you."

coin.amount = 0
coin()

purse = 0
coin2()
```

Comment: So what's the matter?

Comment: I'm not experienced in what the difference is between the two methods and when they're most commonly used. As my post states, I'm wondering which would be the best method for my task and why.

Comment: They can both work, so you can choose one to use that you like. However I prefer `global`.

Answer (score 2):

Neither. Pass the coin amount as an argument, then return the modified value. Now you don't need globals or function attributes at all.

```
def coin3(amount):
    print "You see a coin. Pick it up?"

    choice = raw_input("> ")

    if choice == "yes":
        amount += 1
        print amount
    elif choice == "no":
        print "No monies for you."
    return amount

x = 0
x = coin3(x)
```